# What is the difference between the iptables command and iptables.service? Or what is the significance of iptables.service?

Tags: linux, iptables

I always thought I could only use the `iptables` command if I had the `iptables.service` service installed, but then I found out I was wrong

```bash
┌──[root@vms16.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$systemctl status iptables.service
Unit iptables.service could not be found.
┌──[root@vms16.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 13 -j DROP
┌──[root@vms16.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp --icmp-type 14 -j DROP
```

After adding the rule, it took effect immediately

Without the `iptables.service` service, the command can still be used

```bash
┌──[root@vms16.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$whereis iptables
iptables: /usr/sbin/iptables /usr/libexec/iptables /usr/share/man/man8/iptables.8.gz
┌──[root@vms16.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$which iptables
/usr/sbin/iptables
```

I'm curious why we need `iptables.service`  and what it means, for simplicity we can use `firewalld.service`.

---

```bash
┌──[root@vms16.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$yum -y install  iptables-services.x86_64 > /dev/null
┌──[root@vms16.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$systemctl status iptables.service
● iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

I installed it and found only the configuration file

```bash
┌──[root@vms16.liruilongs.github.io]-[~]
└─$rpm -qlc iptables
/etc/sysconfig/ip6tables-config
/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config
```

What else does `iptable.service` do?

Can I assume so?  `iptables` is kernel related and does not require `iptables.service` to be installed to work, but I see a lot of people reloading configuration files and restarting `iptable.service` after changing `iptable` rules, is that the right idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `iptables` command is used to add or delete rules and chains and can be used without the service file. What `iptables.service` does is to automatically load a saved ruleset on boot and to unload the rules at shutdown. There's a few safety checks in the scripts, like setting default chain policies to ACCEPT on shutdown, to prevent the system from having unusable rulesets. If you want to manually load rules every time you boot the system you can, the service just makes it easier.

`firewalld` presents a simpler interface to defining rules than `iptables` but that is really the major difference. And underneath the covers, `firewalld` uses `iptables` to implement the rules. Personally, I prefer using `iptables` but I have gotten used to the configuration over the years. The choice of `iptables` or `firewalld` is really up to what you're comfortable with.

Comment: Thank you very much, it solved my doubts. Am I to understand that the rules configured with iptables are temporary, in-memory behavior (like `/proc`), not persistent, and if the system is rebooted, the rules are gone unless you export the data before shutting down. `iptables.service` automatically saves these rules and loads them automatically after a reboot. @doneal24

Comment: @山河以无恙 Your understanding is correct. Any changes made by the `iptables` command will disappear when you reboot unless you save them and then reload after the boot.